# Passing pointer to 2D array position as function argument and changing where it points to

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, 2d

So I am trying to make snakes and ladders game using 2D arrays and pointers using C. Here's my code so far:

```
int main(){

    char arr[3][3] = {{' ', ' ', ' '}, {' ', ' ', ' '}, {' ', ' ', ' '}};
    char *ptra;

    arr[0][0] = 'a';

    *ptra = arr[0][0];

    movePlayers(arr, ptra);

    return 0;
}
```

These are the functions I am using.

```
void movePlayers(char arr[3][3], char *ptr){

    *(*(arr + 1) + 0) = *ptr;

    printf("+----+----+----+\n");
    printf("| %c  | %c  | %c  |\n", arr[2][0], arr[2][1], arr[2][2]);
    printf("+----+----+----+\n");
    printf("| %c  | %c  | %c  |\n", arr[1][2], arr[1][1], arr[1][0]);
    printf("+----+----+----+\n");
    printf("| %c  | %c  | %c  |\n", arr[0][0], arr[0][1], arr[0][2]);
    printf("+----+----+----+\n");
   
}
```

I am trying to make the `'a'` in `arr[0][0]` move one column to the right.

This is only a prototype though as I need to use dice values to add there. Anyway, when I run the program, the board from the function `movePlayers` does not show and I do not know if it really did move the value 'a' to `a[0][1]`.

I have tried printing the board itself after running through that function but it just shows `'a'` in its initial position and not the place where I want it.

How do I go about this? Much of your help will be appreciated.

Comment: *ptra=a[0][0] make no sense and could lead to error. May be you want ptra=&a[0][0]. Also the order of cell in print is not correct.

Comment: `*(*(arr + 1) + 0) = *ptr;` hmm.. is this an exercise in making code complicated? Don't do such things... just don't

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the pointer passed as argument, if you change the value stored in the address it points to the change will be relfected in the caller, but if you're going to change the *value* of the pointer, ***i.e.***, where it points to, your argument will need to be a pointer to pointer.

The rationale is that in C arguments are passed by value, changing the *value* of the pointer inside the function doesn't reflect on the caller.

Here is an example of how you should do it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
```

```
void movePlayers(char arr[3][3], char** p) //<-- pointer to pointer
{
    int pos_x = rand() % 3; // random positions for sample
    int pos_y = rand() % 3;

    **p = ' '; // remove token from old position

    *p = &arr[pos_y][pos_x]; // pointing to the new position

    **p = 'a'; // print player token in the new position
}
```

```
// separate function to print the board
void printBoard(char arr[3][3])
{
    printf("+----+----+----+\n");
    printf("| %c  | %c  | %c  |\n", arr[2][0], arr[2][1], arr[2][2]);
    printf("+----+----+----+\n");
    printf("| %c  | %c  | %c  |\n", arr[1][2], arr[1][1], arr[1][0]);
    printf("+----+----+----+\n");
    printf("| %c  | %c  | %c  |\n", arr[0][0], arr[0][1], arr[0][2]);
    printf("+----+----+----+\n");
}
```

```
int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    char arr[3][3] = {{' ', ' ', ' '}, {' ', ' ', ' '}, {' ', ' ', ' '}};

    char* pos = &arr[0][0];    // point to initial position
    *pos = 'a';                // add player token
    
    printBoard(arr);           // print current position

    movePlayers(arr, &pos);     // move, pass the address of the pointer

    printBoard(arr);           // print current position

    movePlayers(arr, &pos);     // move
    
    printBoard(arr);           // print current position
    
}
```

Possible output:

```
+----+----+----+
|    |    |    |
+----+----+----+
|    |    |    |  // 1st table
+----+----+----+
| a  |    |    |
+----+----+----+
+----+----+----+
|    |    |    |
+----+----+----+
|    |    |    |  // 2nd table
+----+----+----+
|    |    | a  |
+----+----+----+
+----+----+----+
|    |    |    |
+----+----+----+
| a  |    |    |  // 3rd table
+----+----+----+
|    |    |    |
+----+----+----+
```

The code is just moving the player around, as a sample, of course you need to add your own game logic to make the moves reflect the dice rolls, namely the movement arithmetic.

Comment: hey! thanks for this this really helped me out on my code here's what I got so far and it has been working pretty well!! ill place it as an answer since it wont fit here ehe